# JQuery mobile, href doesn't show as a button

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, button, href

for school I need to make an jquery mobile application.
The problem is the if I place a link in my code using href it doesn't show up as a button. Can someone please help?
The code I attached to this question is of the page where it doesn't show a button but only a link.

So I want the link "binas" and the link "antwoord" to appear as a button.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Informatica</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

  <link href="css/codiqa.ext.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/informatica.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/codiqa.ext.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>



<div data-role="page" data-control-title="Opdracht 1" data-theme="b"
id="page">
  <div data-role="panel" id="binas" data-position="right"> 
    <h2>BINAS</h2>
    <p>Tabel 349b:<br>
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15</p>
  </div> 
    <div data-role="panel" id="panel" data-position="left" data-display="reveal"
    data-theme="a">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="h" data-inset="false">
            <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">
                Menu
            </li>
            <li data-theme="a">
                <a href="home.html" data-transition="none">
                    Home
                </a>
            </li>
            <li data-theme="a">
                <a href="about.html" data-transition="none">
                    about
                </a>
            </li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">
                Opdrachten
            </li>
            <li data-theme="e">
                <a href="opdracht1.html" data-transition="none">
                    Opdracht 1
                </a>
            </li>
            <li data-theme="e">
                <a href="opdracht2.html" data-transition="none">
                    Opdracht 2
                </a>
            </li>
            <li data-theme="e">
                <a href="opdracht3.html" data-transition="none">
                    Opdracht 3
                </a>
            </li>
            <li data-theme="e">
                <a href="opdracht4.html" data-transition="none">
                    Opdracht 4
                </a>
            </li>
            <li data-theme="e">
                <a href="opdracht5.html" data-transition="none">
                    Opdracht 5
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <a data-controltype="panelbutton" data-role="button" href="#panel" data-icon="bars"
        data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left">
        </a>
        <h3>
            Opdracht 1
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" class="ui-content">
      <p>We beginnen met een makkelijke vraag,<br>
      als je het anwoord op de vraag weet klikt u op &quot;antwoord&quot;</p>
      <p>De vraag:<br>
        Welk heel getal licht boven 9 maar onder de 11?</p>
     <a href="#binas"  data-role="button" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Binas</a>



             <a href="#antwoord" data-role="button" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">Antwoord</a>

    <div data-role="popup" id="antwoord" class="ui-content">
      <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">X</a>
 <h1>Het antwoord op de vraag is:</h1>
 <h3>10</h3>

  </div>





    </div>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Provide at least relevant HTML markup regarding your `link`. And relevant CSS, if any

Comment: please show some of your code that you are having issues with, explain what you have tried to resolve the issue already

Answer (score 0):

Simply placing `href=""` does not mean you're turning something into <kbd>BUTTON</kbd> :)

```
<a href="http://coffee.bar/aboutus.html">ABOUT</a>
```

You need to style the above **Anchor** using CSS

```
<button>YEY I'm a button that does nothing</button>
```

Button does not accepts `href=""` as attribute.

Comment: But in the panel i use the links are showing up as a button, how is that possible?

Comment: @Thijs how should I know that?

Comment: I am sorry I tough maybe you know it